# Position vector, length/modulus function and differentials

Tags: vectors

If $\vec r$ and is the position vector of a point in motion and $r$ is its length/modulus/magnitude/size, then:

Can it be true that:

$$\|\mbox{d} \vec r\| \neq \mbox{d}r? $$
I think that this is true in circular motion, but if this question is generic, i.e., for almost all cases, then do you think this is correct to say?

**EDIT:**  Thanks for the very prompt answers and comments, but please tell me, if this question is given in an exam, which option would you mark? (As a student, I am very interested in understanding physics, but at the end of the day, I also have to think of the exam point of view...)

Comment: In circular motion $|d \vec r| \not = 0$ while $dr = 0$. In fact, $|d \vec r| = dr$ is true only for radial motion.

Comment: @Johannes what do you mean by radial?

Comment: any motion along a straight line through the origin.

Comment: @Johannes How important is through the origin? Is that a compulsary condition?

Answer (score 2):

For any generic motion, $|d\vec{r}|$ represents the **magnitude of the infinitesimal change** in the **vector** $\vec r$. That means that both change in magnitude and in direction will be reflected in $|d\vec r|$.

Whereas $dr$ represents the **infinitesimal change in magnitude**(look how those two words reverse) of $\vec r$. This means that it will only reflect change in magnitude, and not the change in direction of the vector.

From this we can say that $|d\vec r| = dr$ if and only if the direction of $\vec r$ is not changing, i.e. the particle is executing linear motion. I think in all other cases the equality won't hold true.

Answer (score 0):

No -- for a simple counter-example, consider uniform circular motion. $\mathrm dr=0$, but $\left|\mathrm d\vec r\right|=\mathrm d\theta$, because the direction is changing.